# Auto detect location (city & state), and put that information into input and select fields, respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, geolocation

I've been looking over the Geolocation API, as well as the jQuery Geolocation API, and have yet to find a good solution to what I'm trying to do.

Ultimately, I want users to be able to click on an icon in the city location input, the browser to detect their city and state, and then that information automatically populated in the fields, with the city field being a basic input and the state being a select.

```
<div class="search">
  <a href="autodetect-here"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span></a>
  <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="City" />
  <select>

<option selected="state">State</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
```

Comment: The code you've posted is missing your attempt.  What have you tried and in what way is it not working?

Comment: So you want a use to select the state and then the system figure out their city, or is there a button separate from the above code that selects both state and code?

Comment: I'm still working on an attempt. Nothing I've done has come close as I'm in unfamiliar territory. The fa-map-marker icon is what I want to use to trigger geolocation.

Comment: @ChrisOwens: Then it seems you've asked here a bit prematurely.  As a general rule of thumb, when asking "How do I do X?" on Stack Overflow the answer is usually to review the documentation and examples of X.  We don't seek to replace existing documentation/tutorials/etc.  In the majority of cases, you'll find that the problem is easily solvable once you try.  Once you have made some attempt, if there's still something that isn't working (an error message that you don't understand, an unexpected result in a specific operation, etc.) then we can help with that.

Comment: Yes I figured as much. Apologies, but I was looking for direction rather than someone to do it for me, which I got. I will update once I have something working so that this post is of some value to those that may find it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HTML5 geolocation API to get the longitude and latitude, and then send those coordinates to an API such as Google's Geocoding API. This will return you an address which you can parse the city and state from.

[HTML5 Geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

[Google geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding)

> Note: As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure
>   contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin
>   (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer
>   function.